# ajax POST data empty in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tried multiple solutions posted in other similar threads, but nothing seems to help.

I am trying to create a screenshot of the current page with html2canvas and send that to the user specified email address with php.

How I handle the canvas creation and ajax post:

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  values = $('#email').val();
  html2canvas($("#blob"), {
    background: '#fff',
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      theCanvas = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

      $.ajax({
        url: "email.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          'canvas': theCanvas
        },
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      }).done(function(response) {
        alert('success');
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('FAILED! ERROR: ' + errorThrown);

      });
    }
  });
});
```

Looking at the results in email.php with

```html
print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<BR />";
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
print "DATA: <pre>";
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST);
```

results in:

CONTENT_TYPE: 
DATA:
string(0) ""
array(0) {
}

Which means $_POST['canvas'] is also empty.
How can I properly send the data in order to email the image to the user?

Comment: Use browser debug tools and see if the data is sent to the server.
Also, where is theCanvas defined?

Comment: Are there any js errors in your console? Is the `done` or `fail` event handler triggered? What's the result of `console.log(theCanvas);`?

Comment: I get the succeed message and looking at the network tab in chrome shows that the data is populated with the correct string.

Comment: `$("#submit")` what is it? `type='submit' || type='button'` if `submit` then you should stop the form submission with `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: `$("#submit").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //<----add this`

Comment: also, unless intended, theCanvas without var is now in a global scope.

Comment: submit is type='submit'. Added the preventDefault(); but still the same result.